# Highcharts CDN issue with IE8

Tags: highcharts

The highchart galleries at

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

don't render for me on IE8. All works fine on Firefox/Chrome but IE8 (of course) complains about "Invalid character, Line 1 Char 1, http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js".

Could this be due to file compression format used on the code.highcharts.com CDN?
Does anyone else have this issue? I am on a corporate network, so maybe this is some kind of proxy server issue?

Update:

Browser version: IE 8.0.7601.17514

According to whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/ this version of IE8 (or more likely the corporate proxy) is NOT requesting compressed content.

According to web-sniffer.net, the highcharts CDN delivers GZIP'd content even when the request header does not indicate GZIP support - so I think this may be the problem.

Sebastian:

Can the highcharts/highstock CDN be updated to support delivery of uncompressed content when requested?

Comment: Which version of IE8 do you have?

Comment: Version: IE 8.0.7601.17514

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems many proxy servers admins don't allow compressed javascript modules:

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/11/11/whos-not-getting-gzip/

So it would be nice if the Highcharts CDN didn't force compression. Until that changes the best I can suggest is try to load from Highcharts CDN, fallback to your own server if that fails. Perhaps like this;

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/1.2/highstock.js"></script>
<script>!window.Highcharts && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="../js/highstock/highstock.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/1.2/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>!window.Highcharts.post && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="../js/highstock/modules/exporting.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Highcharts library this problem can be solved by using a different CDN such as:

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/2.3.5/highcharts.js

Unfortunately, the HighStock library isn't held on cdnjs, or any other CDN that supports uncompressed download (as of APR 2013).